# Is there a Lambda-Warmer package for dotnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cold-start

I want to keep my AWS Lambda instances warm (even after the default warm time of 5 minutes). I saw good packages like [this](https://github.com/jeremydaly/lambda-warmer) but unable to find any good examples using dotnet.

Could you suggest a Lambda-Warmer package for dotnet which could do the following, please?

- keep the Lambda warm even after 5 minutes
- keep concurrent instances warm (not just a single instance)

Comment: Is something like that really needed now that Lambda supports provisioned concurrency? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html

Comment: If provisioned concurrency doesn't work for you, then Lambda might be the wrong solution and you should look into Fargate.

Comment: I set up provisioned concurrency. However, the Lambda containers are still dropped after 5 minutes.

Comment: lambda warmups do not help if the lambda scales as they need to spawn new instances which again have cold starts

Comment: When I set 10 provisioned concurrency, won't 10 Lambda instances always be running & warm?